# Get selected item value from listbox

Tags: listbox

```
public void select(int z)
{

    ListBox1.SelectedIndex = z;

    ListBox1.SelectedItem = ListBox1.Items[z];                

    ListBoxItem 
    selectedItem=ListBox1.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(this.ListBox1.SelectedItem)    
    as ListBoxItem;

    selectedItem.Focus();

}
```

In this method I'm trying to select element in the listbox, But the reference variable carrying value is null which is returning by the selection code.

"ListBox1.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(this.ListBox1.SelectedItem) as ListBoxItem;"

I have debugged my code and keenly observed that the values are coming into the ListBox1 object, but still it is returning a null value.

Answer (score 0):

```
ListBoxItem selectedItem = ListBox1.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(this.ListBox1.SelectedItem) as ListBoxItem;
TextBox1.Text = selectedItem.Content.ToString();
```

or is it
    TextBox1.Context = selectedItem.Content.ToString();

Good luck :)